# Google cloud storage - signed urls - Is there an upper limit on the number of issuances per hour for A?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#code-samples

I'm issuing signed url by using getSignedUrl (node).

Is there an upper limit on the number of issuances for getSignedUrl?

Specifically, I want to publish about 7,000 times per hour.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the SignedUrl with the client library, and according with how you use it, you can

- Invoque the [service account API signBlob method](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob). You have a [limit to 60000 blob signatures per minutes](https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas). *It's not signature method*
- Sign locally the url with the private key contains in a service account key file (it's the case of your code sample). Because the signature is local (no API invocation), you have no limit on this method.
- Sign against the metadata server (it's also the case of your code when deployed on a Google Cloud service, such as, Cloud Function, Compute Engine (and derived: GKE, Dataflow, Dataproc), Cloud Run, App Engine,...). Here again, no limit/quotas documented for the metadata server, but the signature is performed with the Service Account API signBlob method, and the [limit of 60000 blob signatures per minutes](https://cloud.google.com/iam/quotas) is enforced.

So, for your use case, you won't be annoyed with the limits on the number of SignUrl that you can perform over 1H